# Follow a sibling in Selenium/Python

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I want to enter a text in a text area. The HTML code is as follows:

```
<li class="order-unavailable string-type-key string-block clear-fix status-  require_changes expanded working autogrowed activity-opened" data-string_status="require_changes" data-master_unit_count="22" data-string_id="2394473">
<div class="key-area clear-fix">
<div class="key-area-container-one clear-fix">
    <div class="key-area-container-two">
        <div class="col-50 col-left">
            <div class="string-controls">
                <a class="control-expand-toggle selected" href="#"></a>
                <a class="control-activity-toggle " href="#">2</a>
                <input class="control-select-string" type="checkbox">
            </div>
            <div class="master-content">
        </div>
        <div class="col-50 col-right slave-side-container">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="activity-area clear-fix">
<div class="col-50 col-left">
<div class="col-50 col-right">
    <div class="comment-area-inner">
        <h3>Add comment</h3>
        <div class="comment-container">
        <textarea class="comment-content" name="comment_content"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <strong>Notification settings</strong>
        <p>The people you select will get an email when you post this comment. They'll also be notified by email every time a new comment is added.</p>
        <div class="notification-settings">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The textarea component name is `comment-content`

The xpath of the textarea is:

```
/html/body/div/section/ol/li[16]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/textarea
```

This is the code I am using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//div[@title=\"NOTIFICATION_HOMEPAGE_REDIRECT_CHANGED_SITE\"]
/following-sibling::div[2]/div[2]/div/div/textarea").send_keys("Test comment")
```

Can someone hekp me how to frame the sibling tag?

```
div[2]/div[2]/div/div/textarea
```

The tag before the following-sibling keyword is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the textarea and enter something,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//textarea[@class='comment-content']').send_keys('Test Comment')
```

For xpath, you can use tool [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firepath/) plugin for Firefox

Comment: I cannot directly use the `class='comment-content'`, because there are nested components with the same name. So I have to first use `title` and then use `sibling`

Comment: What about `//textarea[@name='comment_content']`. If still can't be used, should you give me full html source? It will be much helpful.